# Sending a query string in rails controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails controller test, how does one send in a query string to the 'get' method?
For example, for the url `www.abc.com/categories?type=10`.

In my test I would start with: `get :index`

but then how do I pass in the query string to it?

Answer (score 3):

This should work in your controller test:

```
get :index, type: 10
```

Comment: Getting UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action => index, :type => '10'.....} Could it be that it's being passed as /categories/10 instead of /categores?type=10?

Comment: The params look alright, can you post the code for the route you wrote for that specific controller/action?

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5 you do like:

```
path_params = {format: :json, project_id: "OSE"}
get get_test_cases_url(**path_params), params: {case_ids: ["NON-9450", "NON-12345", "OCP-9361"]}
```

`get_test_cases` is name of your route. The `path_params` are all params needed to construct URL for the route. And this is passing one array type query `GET` param.